# What does .byte mean in this asm line?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am revisiting code that I wrote a while ago that does some math on large numbers.  When I wrote the code, the lab had a few x86s that were split between 32 and 64 bits.  My work was on UltraSPARCs, and I vaguely remember pulling this line of code from an Intel manual to be sure that the code was being used on a 64-bit CPU.

```
unsigned long x[4];
x[0] = 0;
x[1] = 0;
x[2] = 0;
x[3] = 0;
asm volatile(".byte 15;.byte 162" : "=a"(x[0]),"=b"(x[1]),"=c"(x[3]),"=d"(x[2]) : "0"(0) );
```

If x[0] was 0, all was well and the program started chugging away.

Can anyone explain to me what this line of code actually does?

Comment: 15 is 0x0F, so I would guess it is some opcode. Multiply?

Comment: 0FA2 (15, 162 in decimal) is the CPUID instruction. I imagine there are easier ways to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytes `.byte 15` and `.byte 162` represent the `CPUID` instruction.
When it executes you get results in `EAX`, `EBX`, `ECX`, and `EDX`.

These results will be stored in the array elements:

```
x[0] <- EAX
x[1] <- EBX
x[2] <- EDX
x[3] <- ECX
```

Comment: Thank you!  What a silly way to specify the CPUID instruction of 0FA2. I guess at the time the assembly must not have supported CPUID or something strange like that.

Comment: @bdegnan : Appears to be the case that they were ensuring that a GCC compiler that may not have supported CPUID opcode would still work. I noticed in one such change online code went from CPUID to the the .byte encoding for specifically that reason: http://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/code/27857